# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql

I am usign this code to add new column in my table but can't get success it shows me this error. Column name is `$paper_name`.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near

```
 $query1 ="ALTER TABLE User_data ADD '".$paper_name."' VARCHAR( 255 )" or die(mysqli_error($con));
                    mysqli_query($con,$query1)or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: yep, this sql looks invalid to me. "alter table add what"?

Comment: Add $paper_name. `$paper = 'some text'`.

Comment: What is the resulting SQL, with all substitutions done?

Comment: It adds new blank column to table `User_data`.

Comment: It adds, or it raises an error? `$query1`, show me its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `'` where you need a back tick

```
 "ALTER TABLE User_data ADD `".$paper_name."` VARCHAR(255)"
```

Values are in single quotes, field names are in back ticks

You could use...

```
"ALTER TABLE User_data ADD `$paper_name` VARCHAR(255)"
```

...to make it a little more readable (my opinion) . Eliminate the `".` and `."` around `$paper_name`.  Since your statement is already enclosed in `"` the `$paper_name` variable will be evaluated properly.